# After installing the NServiceBus NuGet package my project does not contain any additional DLL references

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nservicebus

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and want to add NServiceBus to my project.

Whether I use the Package Manager GUI, or the Package Manager Console, after installing the NuGet package, the project does not contain any additional assemblies in the project References, and therefore  cannot reference any of the NServiceBus classes from my code.

If I manage packages for the solution it says that the package is installed, and when I open the packages.config file it contains this line:

```
<package id="NServiceBus" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net40" />
```

But there is no NServiceBus classes available to my application.

Comment: Try deleting the packages folder and the packages.config file and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your project is .Net 4.0. NServiceBus v5 requires .Net 4.5

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the problem, thank you. Annoying that it just fails silently!!